# How do I update the a textview to show the number of checkboxes selected in android?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, textview

I have managed to retrieve the number of checkboxes selected after clicking a button in the activity, however I want to be able to update a textview in the activity to show the user the number of items selected.

How would I do this?

Here is my code so far (in the listadapter which is extending BaseAdapter):

---

```
private ArrayList<Compare> selectedComparePlaces = new ArrayList<Compare>();
private int numSelected;
...


// in the getView method
TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.compareSubheading);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.compareCheckbox);
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
       if(isChecked) {
           numSelected++;
           selectedComparePlaces.add(compareList.get(position));
           // should update the textview to say "[numberselected]/2 selected"
           // tv.setText(numSelected + "/2 selected");
   } else {
       numSelected--;
       selectedComparePlaces.remove(compareList.get(position));
       // should update the textview to say "[numberselected]/2 selected"
       // tv.setText(numSelected + "/2 selected");
   }
}               
});
```

I have tried using:
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(numSelected) + "/2 selected");

But both attempts gave me a nullPointerException on the tv.setText line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the TextView function :

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyTextViewId);
myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(myNumber));
```

Can you show us your code ? You need to cast here

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
 textview.setText( "" + count ):
```